# How to display a variable value on a button pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically I am making a COVID-19 bot which tracks all the cases and deaths around the world.

```
def total_cases_counter():
    # create the button
    button = pygame.Rect(63, 183, 105, 40)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0, 0, 0], button)
    button_font = pygame.font.Font('GOODDP__.TTF', 32)
    button_text = button_font.render(total_cases, True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(button_text, (205, 410))
```

This is my function to display a total cases counter which I create a button for and then try to display the total_cases which I have as a variable that is updated from an API. The issue I have is I do not know how to display the variable value (number of total cases around the world) over the button. I tried using the render function but the first parameter has to be a string which means I cannot display my variable.

Comment: Whats wrong with using a string for your button name???

Comment: no thats not what I meant. I mean I want to display the total number of cases which is just a variable total_cases = 35725734 on top of the button. Some number basically.

Comment: yeah i got that, but you can just wrap the variable in a call to string to convert it to a string. like, `total=1234; button_string = str(total)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your variable "total_cases" is integer right? If so, then try it:

`def total_cases_counter():
    # create the button
    button = pygame.Rect(63, 183, 105, 40)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0, 0, 0], button)
    button_font = pygame.font.Font('GOODDP__.TTF', 32)
    button_text = button_font.render(str(total_cases), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(button_text, (205, 410))`

As you can see, i changed the type of your variable by using "str(total_cases)".

P.S. Is total_cases global variable?